# How can I get 'synthesisCompleted' at the very end of audio? (Microsoft azure TTS)

Tags: azure, events, text-to-speech, voice

I'm working on this example (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/javascript/browser/text-to-speech/index.html) that use Microsoft Azure Voice service in order to convert text to speech.
What I want is to get an event when the speech end so I can do other things. Right now it sends me an event (the 'synthesisCompleted' one) that is supposed to be triggered on the end of the speech but actually it is sent earlier (like  I cannot figure out how to catch the very end of the audio.
 Can anybody help me? I don't know if it can be helpful but I saw there is also a 'stream' argument in 'speakTextAsync'.

Comment: Little update: I have found that I can pause and resume the player defining  `var player = new SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();` and then calling it like `player.pause()` or `player.resume()`, but still cannot find how to catch the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to do it.
If anybody else needs the solution too here is my function:

```
    var SpeechSDK;

    function textToSpeech(txt){
      var player = new SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();
      player.onAudioEnd = function (_) {
          ##do something##
        };
      var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);
      const speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(CONFIG.voiceSubKey, CONFIG.voiceLoc);  
      speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = "***";
      speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = CONFIG.voiceLan;
      speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = CONFIG.voiceName;
      
      var synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
      
      const complete_cb = function (result) {
        if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
          console.log("synthesis finished");
        } else if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled) {
          console.log("synthesis failed. Error detail: " + result.errorDetails);
        }
        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
      };
      const err_cb = function (err) {
        window.console.log(err);
        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
      };

      synthesizer.synthesisStarted  = function (s, e) {
        console.log("Speech started");
      };
      synthesizer.speakTextAsync(txt,
        complete_cb,
        err_cb);
           
    } 
       
    if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;}
```

Comment: You are an absolute legend. It's not immediately apparent from the above, but the key is the onAudioEnd event, then following the chain of construction to the SpeechSynthesizer.

Comment: this is insane. why does azure have to make everything so hard.